# Magento 1.9: Double megamenu

Tags: magento-1.9, menu, megamenu

In the navigation menu there are 2 different menus with EM Megamenu.
I set the top one via the widget section, but the one below I do not know how to remove it.

Comment: Is there any cache for the Mega Menu ? If so , clean it .

Comment: I've already cleaned it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself,
I have deleted both Magento caches